# count the number of results of mysql query with loop

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a loop in mysql, so that the results of one query informs the second. This is my current query set:

```
 select @post_date := from_unixtime(post_date)
 from posts
 where post_date > unix_timestamp('2012-10-20') and nsfw=1;

 select @countofpost := count(@post_date);

 while @countofpost > 0 DO

  select count(*)
  from live_sharedata.users
  where joined between @post_date and (@post_date + 21600) and joined_site_id="RS";

  set @countofpost = @countofpost -1;

 end while;
```

The error I receive is [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'while @countofpost > 0 DO.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm looking at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/while.html which says that it is the way to do a mysql while loop. I'm running 5.1.7.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Run `SELECT @post_date;` - does it show you the right information?  Variables in MySQL cannot hold arrays, or multiple items.  If you need the variables to hold multiple objects, you need to use `CURSOR`.
2. For your `select @countofpost := count(@post_date);` query, you could also re-write it as `SET  @countofpost = FOUND_ROWS();`.  `FOUND_ROWS()` returns the number of rows that would be returned were there no LIMIT clause, so there is no need to run the `COUNT()` command in the set of rows.

I believe, that you need to re-write your query using cursors, as (I think) that you expect the first `SELECT @post_date := from_unixtime(post_date) ...` query to return multiple objects.  Please look at the [Reference Manual's Cursor section](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cursors.html) for more information.